# Java Parallel Network Requests and List Updates

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, network-programming

I am limited to a 1-core machine on AWS, but after measuring the time to complete all of my http requests and check their results, two of them together require as much time combined to fetch data as the remaining fifty requests (roughly 2 minutes).

I don't want to bloat my code more than I have to, but I know parallelism and asynchrony can seriously cut down the execution time for this task. I want to launch the two big requests on their own threads so they can go out while the others are running, but I store the results of these http requests in a list currently.

Can you access different (guaranteed) elements of a list at the same time as long as the data is initialized beforehand? I've seen the concurrent list and parallel list, but the one isn't parallel, and the other reallocates the entire list on every modification, so neither is a particularly sane option.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Can you just create your own threads, and dispatch you request list into different threads?

Comment: I tried that and got a very interesting result. I have 3 data sets. If I set up a Thread[] team = new Thread[dataSets.length]; and then let them all spin, the overall throughput is much higher, but even after doing for(int I=0; I < team.length; I++) { if (team[I].isAlive()) { try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch(Exception e) {}} }, on the very last dataSet, despite throwing no exceptions being thrown within the thread, the result array comes out null. The other 19 result arrays are exactly as expected, but for w/e reason, the last result entries are not there following the joins.

Comment: The index for setting the list entry to the result array is still correct within the thread too, but it consistently fails. Is there some sort of delay happening in the process of the thread dying for the results to be committed back?

Comment: I discovered the Thread.isAlive() method is useless. It just tells you whether or not it's currently active, not whether or not it's been retired. If I loop over the thread team and just use thread.join(), all of a sudden all of the data is properly updated.

Why is this? The name of the method has nothing to do with what it accomplishes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a concurrent list in Java. I'm assuming that you are referring to a concurrent hash set (using `newSetFromMap`) and your "parallel list" refers to a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

You most definitely can use the former option to store update data.

A better way to solve your problem of updating data asynchronously is to just simply use a non-thread-safe collection for your worker thread and then push them all at once when you're done to a thread-safe collection that you use to aggregate all your requests.

So something like:

```
Set<Response> aggregate = Collections.newSetFromMap(...);
executor.execute(...);
...

// Workers
Set<Response> local = new HashSet<>();
populate(local);

aggregate.addAll(local);
```

You might want to use various synchronizers if you want your response data to be ordered in a specific way, such as having all your responses from Request 1 to be together. If you only need to move **one** request from each worker, use a thread safe transfer or a singleton collection.